# How to split and distribute test evenly on available jenkins slave?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

Let's say we have a Java project with 1000 testclasses.
Let's say we have 4 Jenkins slaves.

Is there a way to split and run 250 (1000/4) testclasses on the 4 available slaves ?

The closest I found is the [Parallel Test Executor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parallel+Test+Executor+Plugin) but according to comment it need previous successful build to split tests.

I am sure this is a simple solution to increase speed testing but I can't find lot of resources about this scenario ? Has nobody ever wanted to split and distribute those test ? Is this possible ?

I can manualy create 4 jobs corresponding to 250 tests but I don't want to manage the split manualy. Sooner we will forget new test. Splitting by package woud be a acceptable too.

I am using gradle

*I am new with Jenkins, And I have create simple freestyle job that automate what I am doing manualy.
I am looking to improve this automation set-up.*

Comment: Are you using the Jenkins pipeline syntax to create your Jenkins job?

Comment: Not currently but I can. Updated question to present my situation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an Jenkins job using the Jenkins Pipeline syntax.  You can use the parallel keyword to execute the tests in parallel. Inside your method, you can create logic to determine what tests to run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def stashName = ""

def agentName = 'dart'
properties([buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '8')), pipelineTriggers([])])
timestamps{

    stage("Initialize the Pipe")
            {
                node("dart")
                        {
                            echo "Pipeline has initialized the node."
                        }
            }

    node("dart")
            {
                stage("Checkout Source")
                        {
                            checkoutFromGit()
                        }
                stage("Building Code and Testing")
                        {
                            def parallelTests = [:]
                            def totalNodes = 5
                            for (int i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
                                def modIndex = i
                                parallelTests["Unit Test ${modIndex}"] = runTest(totalNodes, modIndex)
                            }
                            parallel parallelTests
                        }

            }


    stage("Finalize Build")
            {
                echo "Pipeline has completed."
            }
}//timestamp



def runTest(numNodes, modNum) {
    return {
                    dir('test')
                            {
                                sh 'grade test'

                            } //dir(ui)



    }//return
}//runTest
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel

Comment: This refer to the point in my question I don't want to manage the split manualy. We will sooner forget to add new package. And this doesn't scale with the number of available slave

Comment: You can use the scripted pipeline syntax instead of declarative, and you can write a bit of groovy to determine the best way to split.  I think the limitation will be the gradle task proper depending on how the tests are arranged.

Comment: Splitting by package would be fine ! Is it possible to generate stage like yours automatically foreach package ?

Comment: I updated my answer with some code I used last year.  It still "hard codes" max number of nodes to parallel, but you might be able to ask Jenkins how many agents it has.  Hadn't tried that piece.  In my example, I was hashing certain packages to run on certain nodes, which is why the mod index stuff is there.